# Parametrise or Share DB connection within a test suit

Tags: testing, automation, db2, fitnesse, dbfit

is there any way to share the DB connection within all testcases of a suite?

(I don't like specifying the DB connection in every testcase)
(also if there is any way to parametrise it will make me happy)

Anto

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer try the link...

http://dbfit.github.io/dbfit/docs/reference.html#connect-using-file